# How to route only part of my network traffic through 3G/4G/Tethering?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, routing, tethering

Latelly I've been in the middle of nowhere and my only option is to use my 3G/LTE dongle or tether my phone. The problem is the number of background tasks and updates and everything that consumes my bandwidth. So, I was thinking if there's a way to prevent that. One idea that came to me is to setup some kind of proxy/local routing server that I could configure in the apps I really need to use, like the browser. For the sake of the other apps, I'd seem to be offline.

I'd not like to consider killing the background tasks and/or stopping the auto-updates, because this would be tedious to do every time I needed it.

Is anything like this possible? What are the other alternatives?

**EDIT:** I'm using xubuntu (xfce powered version of ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a (software)firewall and only allow certain outgoing traffic. Depending on the firewall used you could allow certain applications or ip adresses. What distro are you on?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows machine there's a great way to do this in a few minutes because of executable-level blocking w/o extra software.

You want windows firewall in advanced mode. Disable all existing outbound rules first. Go under outbound rules and create a new program based rule. Choose all programs, then on the next page choose block. Then make a rule for your browser that allows traffic. You could also do this by ports, e.g. allowing only outgoing traffic on ports 80,8080,443,etc.

EDIT: For Linux you will need port-based unless you want to add some package I'm not aware of. Something like the following:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state –state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
<and so on>
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```